# When looping over Dataobject, how to display 2 records per column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, silverstripe

When looping over a `DataObject` how do you only display 2x items per column e.g

I need to display the locations as per this design which has 4 columns. I am using boostrap for the columns.

[image]

I have a **Location.php** `Dataobject`

```
class Location extends DataObject {

    public static $default_sort = 'Sort';

    private static $db = array(
        'Sort' => 'Int',
        'City' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Address' => 'Text',
        'PhoneNumber' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'SiteConfigExtension' => 'SiteConfig',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'City',
        'Address',
        'PhoneNumber',
    );


}
```

In my template .ss I have this

```
<% with $SiteConfig %>
    <% loop Locations %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="location-$Pos">
                <h6>$City</h6>
                <div>$Address</div>
                <div>$PhoneNumber</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_with %>
```

Obviously atm this creates a new column for each record in the Dataobject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $First $Last and $MultipleOf(x).  The below will display 2 columns per row. Change MultipleOf(2) to another number to display a different number of columns per row. MultipleOf(3) = 3 columns per row, MultipleOf(4) = 4 columns per row, etc. You will need to update the css class names.

```
  <% with $SiteConfig %>
    <% loop Locations %>
        <% if First %>
            <div class="row">
        <% end_if %>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="location-$Pos">
                <h6>$City</h6>
                <div>$Address</div>
                <div>$PhoneNumber</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <% if MultipleOf(2) %>
          </div><% if not Last %><div class="row"><% end_if %>
        <% else %>
          <% if Last %></div><% end_if %>
      <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
  <% end_with %>
```